# CSS Align span to left bottom of div aligned to right

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align a `span` to left of a `div`, which is aligned to right (`float: right`), but `span`always appears to collide with `div`

```css
* {
  font-family: Lucida Sans Unicode, Lucida Grande, Verdana, Arial;
}
.mw {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
}
.msg {
  float: right;
  background-color: #D80000;
  color: white;
  padding: 0.66em;
  border-radius: 1em;
}
.uns {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 480px; background: yellow; padding: 1em">
  <div class="mw">
    <span class="uns">0</span>
    <div class="msg">Some content</div>
    <br style="clear: both">
  </div>
  <br style="clear: both">
</div>
```

This is what I want to get

[image: This is what I want to reach]

**EDIT:** Using negative left is not a solution, content of `span` can vary, so at bigger number it will again screw up and collide!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `transform: translateX(-100%)` and move `span` to left equal to its width.

```css
* {
  font-family: Lucida Sans Unicode, Lucida Grande, Verdana, Arial;
}
.mw {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
}
.msg {
  float: right;
  background-color: #D80000;
  color: white;
  padding: 0.66em;
  border-radius: 1em;
}
.uns {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 480px; background: yellow; padding: 1em">
  <div class="mw">
    <span class="uns">0</span>
    <div class="msg">Some content</div>
    <br style="clear: both">
  </div>
  <br style="clear: both">
</div>
```

Comment: That doesn't help, when content of <span ..uns> is bigger value like 10000, it screws up again

Comment: It will always be aligned to left as you can see here https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/886/

Comment: This is more of hack `:)` given the OP code is not very good. mixing `float`s with `position:absolute`

Answer (score 1):

If there is no special reason to use `position: absolute`, You can use this.

```
.uns {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  padding-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/kcp0ub96/)

Answer (score 0):

Just add left: -20px to your class.

```
 .uns {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left : -20px;
    }
```

Have a look at this fidlle. https://jsfiddle.net/y6a77fLp/

Comment: Nope, if content of span is like "100000" it again screws up

Answer (score 0):

Add " margin-left: -15px; "  in ***.uns*** class styles.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use flexbox :

```
.mw {    
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end; // Align to the bottom
  // rest of the code
}
```

Here a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/JCornat/huoz4wb5/)

Comment: just answered that ;)

Answer (score 0):

?? late to answer, but what about `vertical-align`, `text-align` + `inline-block` to kick off some `float` since it is about only phrasing content  ?

```css
* {
  font-family: Lucida Sans Unicode, Lucida Grande, Verdana, Arial;
}
.mw {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  text-align: right;
}
.msg {
  background-color: #D80000;
  color: white;
  padding: 0.66em;
  border-radius: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
}
.uns {
  vertical-align: -1em;
  display: inline-block;
}
[style] {overflow:hidden;/* clear in 'n outsider floats */}
```

```html
<div style="width: 480px; background: yellow; padding: 1em">
  <div class="mw">
    <span class="uns">0</span>
    <div class="msg">Some content</div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr/>
<div style="width: 480px; background: yellow; padding: 1em">
  <div class="mw">
    <span class="uns">10 000 000 00</span>
    <div class="msg">Some content</div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr/>
<div style="width: 480px; background: yellow; padding: 1em">
  <div class="mw">
    <span class="uns">10 000<br/>+ it can wrap too</span>
    <div class="msg">Some content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```